# Production server issue with symfony routing.yml

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4

I've an existing project in symfony 1.4

For few new static pages, I added few rules in routing.yml file. Added rules are

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: page, action: index }

career:
  url:   /career
  param: { module: page, action: career }

company:
  url:   /company
  param: { module: page, action: company }

faq:
  url:   /faq
  param: { module: page, action: faq }

presskit:
  url:   /presskit
  param: { module: page, action: presskit }

privacy:
  url:   /privacy
  param: { module: page, action: privacy }

team:
  url:   /team
  param: { module: page, action: team }

terms:
  url:   /terms
  param: { module: page, action: terms }
```

On views/partials, I'm using `<?PHP echo url_for('page/career') ?>`, `<?PHP echo url_for('page/index') ?>` etc for navigation. It is working perfectly fine on local development box producing nav links `domain.com/career`, `domain.com/` respectively.

However on production server, links in navigation were `domain.com/index.php/career`, `domain.com/index.php/` etc. Both development box and production server have same .htaccess file (Symfony 1.4 default .htaccess file). Can someone please suggest what could be the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have this in `settings.yml`

```
prod (or "all", if you want):
  .settings:
    no_script_name:         true
```